# Clear image from browser cache in JSP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm developing a JSP Web application for a university, and there is a personnel picture displayed in user page.

How can i clear this picture from web-browser cache once the user logged out ?

using JSP or javascript

Comment: +1 for the weirdest requirement I've heard today. :)

Answer (score 6):

That's not possible. Your best bet is to just entirely disable the caching of the resource in question. Create a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which does the following job in the `doFilter()` method.

```
HttpServletResponse hsr = (HttpServletResponse) response;
hsr.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate");
hsr.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
hsr.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

and map it on an URL pattern covering the image(s) of interest.

---

**Edit:** if you *actually* don't care about the image being present in the browser cache, but your concrete problem is that different logged-in users basically use the same image URL because it's been served dynamically by some servlet, then you can also solve it by giving every unique user an unique image URL. You can do this by appending for example the user ID as request parameter to the image URL, or including it in the image's path.

```
<img src="profileimage?id=${user.id}" />
```

or

```
<img src="profileimage/${user.id}" />
```

Comment: Depending on your web server, I think you could set up this same type of filter there.

Answer (score 1):

The question clearly doesn't distinguish between client-side and server-side code.

For one thing, when a user closes the web browser, you just can't clear the cache, because the browser's gone.

That said, you can keep track of image changes and append a number to the image URL - this will force the web browser to ignore the cache and load the new image.

Example:

```
File filename = new File("/path/to/profile.png");
long t = filename.lastModified();
System.out.print("<img src='profile.png?"+t+"'/>");
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to track the version of the image. He wants to remove an image from the browser's cache that could only be accessed while logged in. Anyone that has access to that physical computer can now access that image directly from cache, without having to log into the site.

Comment: I didn't say he *wants* to track the version either, I said that he *must* track the image. And the best way to do this (IMHO) is with my method above.