# User needs to clear the cache for new release

Tags: javascript

Everytime we make a release the users need to clear their cache for the new code to take effect. Is there a way to have this done automatically?

Comment: Is this an include on a site?  Is this third-party Javascript that you have no control over the include statement?  Need more details.

Comment: check if desired resourced changed ( probably in serverside code ) , pass that value to client side (statically or dynamically through ajax ) and the in javascript : `if (resource_changed) location.reload(true);` sth like this

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem ?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it. If you are working on nodejs , sailsjs related environment I could give you a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

what about add on default page no cache html tag?

similar to answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a Javascript include on a website then you can just append a query string with an incremented version number.  So one release would be:

```
<script src="codebase.js?v=1"></script>
```

and the next release would be:

```
<script src="codebase.js?v=2"></script>
```

If you're talking about a third-party hosted file that you don't have control over their script include then the problem is more difficult.

Comment: That's actually the technique that we use (appending a new version number) but it still happens. I don't know what can be done about this.

Comment: We are having a discussion about the same issue, in my mind it's a server-side issue. The version number needs to be added to files in some way, maybe a rewrite to include the path or to append the version number as in the example above.
We are running IIS so I have to do some research on it but I think some sort of URL rewrite is the way to go. And to make sure that the page being served is "touch"-ed as well. Suspenders and a belt. :)