# JSON Data load Issue

Tags: javascript, json, browser

I am creating a grails app and loading JSON files in my controller and am faced with a high risk Data issue.

The JSON files are loaded using requests in the index.gsp file of the views part.

I have various drop downs, date slider and charts in my web application using various javascript libraries (d3, jquery, highcharts, dc and crossfilter)

Now, the issue is every dropdown selection loads a new JSON table in the browser, which can be seen in the network part of the browser after pressing F12
So, after a set of selections (depending on json table size) as soon as net data transferred exceeds 200 Mb, the browser and the page becomes very slow, eventually leading to browser/page crash.

So, I started searching for clearing cache memory using javascript and apparently from the results, it's quite tough and not practical as it deals with the security issues of a browser.

[How to programmatically empty browser cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache)

[Clear the cache in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011605/clear-the-cache-in-javascript)

So, I need a method for the browser to clear the cache every time a drop down is selected.

But, Is the JSON file data being loaded in cache memory or something else?
As I also tried clearing cache manually by going to tools ..etc and still the browser crashed.

Can anyone tell me an approach to go about solving the problem?

Two questions mainly :

## 1. Where does the JSON file load data in the browser ( which memory)?

## 2. How do I keep clearing this data to reduce load on the browser?

Any help would be appreciated.

I am currently trying Gzip and other compressions.

Comment: Did anybody ever figure this out, I'm trying to determine the same thing.

Comment: Yes, we did. Use AJAX calls to load data. That's the only way it'll run smoothly in the browsers