# Drupal-Browser Caching

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-7, browser-cache

Why it is necessary to clear the cache of the browser after clearing my site's cache from admin panel?

Every time I have to ask everyone to clear browser cache to see updates. Is there any way to come over this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to clear broser cache then place the below meta tags in head of page.tpl.php

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Source: [How to programmatically empty browser cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache)