# How to clear cache programatically in html?

Tags: javascript, html, caching

I have tried researching to clear cache of my website from meta tag. But none of them are working.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT">
```

tried this one, but I am getting cache in firefox.

To see cache: Type `about:cache` or `about:cache?storage=disk&context=` in address bar.

I tried the below one, its working, but I need to do this programatically.

Enter "about:config" into the Firefox address bar and set:

```
  network.http.use-cache = false
```

Any working solutions in **meta tag** or **Javascript** or **HTML5 manifest** will be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13291751/1675954

Comment: what you are asking is against the "sandbox" principle of todays modern browser. Simply, you cant speak to the browser to do stuff outside of it. if this would work, hackers would have a blast.

Answer (score 1):

> meta tag

No. The `http-equiv` attribute supports [a number of values](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-http-equiv), none of which touch caching.

> Javascript

No. JavaScript is not provided with any APIs that let you override caching.

> HTML5 manifest

No. The manifest lets you mark files to be hard cached for offline use. It provides no mechanism to reducing caching.

---

If you want to tell the browser not to cache something then you have to do it with real HTTP headers.

Comment: How can I use real HTTP headers? Any links you have gone through?

Comment: By configuring your HTTP server (which depends on which server you are using) or generating your page using a server side program (which depends on which programming language you are writing it in).

Comment: I m not getting you @Quentin

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: I m using Java for backend, html codes for frontend, I dont understand what you are saying about "generating your page using server side program"

Comment: It sounds like you are already using a server side program and you have written it in Java. Read up on how to set HTTP headers in whatever variant of Java (J2EE?) you are using.