# Clear cache on page

Tags: javascript

Is it possibile to clear cache on sigle page using javasscript? I know that document.location.reload() will do that. But can it be done without refreshing page?

Comment: Why do you think that you can control the cache?

Comment: More importantly, why do you want to do it? There's possibly a better way to solve whatever problem you have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically empty browser cache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do is to tell it not to cache your page, by sending the appropriate headers or using these meta tags on your HTML :

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'> //clear cache
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>//clear cache with some expire time
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'> // no Cache
```

Answer (score -2):

I can't think of a way to clear cache using Javascript. Probably you should try to append a version number to force the browser to load the new one. For example, change this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

to this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js?version=1"></script>
```