# how to clear the cache on window.location.replace()?

Tags: javascript, caching, window.location

I have a web app that normally requires payment to use but the first session is a free trial.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   if (trial === "true") {
      window.location.replace("freeTrial.html?SD=" + userId);
   }
});
```

If it's the first free trial session, the user is redirected to another page.
The problem is that on the second visit (when `trial==="false"`), the browser (tested in Chrome) has cached the page from the first visit and the user is wrongly redirected.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Look this question i think it's the answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache

Comment: And where is trial set?

Comment: @epascarello it's set in a url parameter