# What is the JavaScript equivalent of "Clear Site Data" in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, cookies, browser-cache

I am looking for a way to trigger the same behavior as "Clear site data" in Chrome Dev tools or as close to the same behavior as possible. I know there are [some things that are not possible i.e. clearing browser cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache), and this doesn't need to be within the scope of this question. I am not sure if Clear Site Data does some special things other than clearing cookies, Web SQL/IndexedDB and unregistering service workers.

I use [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) in some of the projects I work on so cleaning IndexedDB/localStorage is fairly simple and making sure to call `clear` but I am unfamiliar what goes on behind the scenes for other parts or if there's something I may be missing. For context, there are times in my app where I see awkward regressions (I make some updates and they don't update). I have a programmatic trigger that clears localStorage and cookies but it doesn't fix the situation but clicking "Clear Site Data" with everything checked does.

Also side note I also found a W3C spec draft regarding [clear site data headers](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-clear-site-data/)? I am uncertain if this is the direction we may be moving to trigger a clear in site data? Any information would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yikes so after not getting any answers, decided to dig into some source code. I found the repository for [Chrome Devtools](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend) and also the code where they actually call the `this._clear` from the UI [(can be found in resources/ClearStorageView.js)](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/master/front_end/resources/ClearStorageView.js#L120).

```
  _clear() {
    if (!this._securityOrigin)
      return;
    const storageTypes = [];
    for (const type of this._settings.keys()) {
      if (this._settings.get(type).get())
        storageTypes.push(type);
    }

    this._target.storageAgent().clearDataForOrigin(this._securityOrigin, storageTypes.join(','));

    const set = new Set(storageTypes);
    const hasAll = set.has(Protocol.Storage.StorageType.All);
    if (set.has(Protocol.Storage.StorageType.Cookies) || hasAll) {
      const cookieModel = this._target.model(SDK.CookieModel);
      if (cookieModel)
        cookieModel.clear();
    }

    if (set.has(Protocol.Storage.StorageType.Indexeddb) || hasAll) {
      for (const target of SDK.targetManager.targets()) {
        const indexedDBModel = target.model(Resources.IndexedDBModel);
        if (indexedDBModel)
          indexedDBModel.clearForOrigin(this._securityOrigin);
      }
    }

    if (set.has(Protocol.Storage.StorageType.Local_storage) || hasAll) {
      const storageModel = this._target.model(Resources.DOMStorageModel);
      if (storageModel)
        storageModel.clearForOrigin(this._securityOrigin);
    }

    if (set.has(Protocol.Storage.StorageType.Websql) || hasAll) {
      const databaseModel = this._target.model(Resources.DatabaseModel);
      if (databaseModel) {
        databaseModel.disable();
        databaseModel.enable();
      }
    }

    if (set.has(Protocol.Storage.StorageType.Cache_storage) || hasAll) {
      const target = SDK.targetManager.mainTarget();
      const model = target && target.model(SDK.ServiceWorkerCacheModel);
      if (model)
        model.clearForOrigin(this._securityOrigin);
    }

    if (set.has(Protocol.Storage.StorageType.Appcache) || hasAll) {
      const appcacheModel = this._target.model(Resources.ApplicationCacheModel);
      if (appcacheModel)
        appcacheModel.reset();
    }

    this._clearButton.disabled = true;
    const label = this._clearButton.textContent;
    this._clearButton.textContent = Common.UIString('Clearing...');
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._clearButton.disabled = false;
      this._clearButton.textContent = label;
    }, 500);
  }
```

I think the tl;dr is naturally their Clear Site data hooks into the checkbox options they have on the form which goes through and clears the options. In my original question I was personally wondering if there was something MORE than just that and it does look like they do call at the very top, regardless of what you have checked:

```
this._target.storageAgent().clearDataForOrigin(this._securityOrigin, storageTypes.join(','));
```

Not sure what this was but doing some digging, it looks like it might be some [experimental API for clearing data from origin for Lighthouse apps](https://paulirish.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/Storage/#method-clearDataForOrigin). Personally I'm not sure or feel qualified to say this is correct. Hope this helps people.

If I can make a JavaScript equivalent script I'll try but technically all of Chrome Devtools is in JavaScript :P

Comment: This doesn't seem to provide an answer to the question. Am I wrong?

Comment: @NeithanMax Not truly no. I was hoping for an answer that would be more usable on a typical website (use case you want to trigger this on your webpage on behalf of a user). Unfortunately I didn't get that answer. I ended up looking at what Chrome does behind the scenes. The truth is, it's complicated and a lot of the things aren't invokable from a typical webpage (surprise). I called out the important parts and showed where the code lives. For now I just accepted my own answer because it's as close as I can get but I'm willing to accept a better answer if it comes.