# Clearing cache after user logout in JSP no scriptlet allowed

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I am trying to find a way to prevent users from clicking back the browser to the page after they logout and I figured easiest way is to clear the cache so they have to go back to the login page.

I cannot use a scriptlet code to do so, which is what many of the googled suggestions showed. Is there a way to do this via JSTL or HTML?

Comment: Scriptlet code runs on the server anyway; it is not directly helpful for manipulating the client.  For the same reason, JSTL provides nothing directly useful.

Comment: For its part, HTML has no mechanism to express what you describe, but you can do it by triggering [Javascript embedded in the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache).

Answer (score -1):

use this while you are redirecting to login it will automatically clear cahce

```
 response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");   
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");  
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);  as "stale"
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
```