# How can I store data in the browser so that it does not delete when user clear cache?

Tags: javascript, browser

I need somehow to somehow identify the user / browser if the user has cleared the cache. This somehow I can do?

Comment: You can you html5 local storage.

Comment: Look for HTML5 local storage

Comment: You can look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache for the solution

Comment: What cache are you talking about? What data? How is the data is stored? We need more context to answer your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updated your question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the HTML 5  [FILE API Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/)