# How to clear IE cache for specific site using C# not using JS or jQuery

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to clear IE cache for a site using C# . I am having a Windows application which uses WebBrowser control to login to specific site. But, I am not storing any cache using my program , IE does it by default.
I was trying to understand

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384026(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384049(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383983(v=vs.85).aspx

But I couldn't find a solution out of it.

Comment: You can set headers on the page to prevent it from being cached: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8155121/5894241

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically empty browser cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache)

Comment: Many of the users are already using my application. For future I can use cache control , but my application loads different Site which i cannot control  and it has login.

Comment: [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407) has a detailed info regarding `cache-control`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can Use my class to Clear IE Cache

```
public static class WebBrowserHelper
{
    #region WINAPI        
    [DllImport("wininet",  EntryPoint = "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA",  SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool DeleteUrlCacheEntry(IntPtr lpszUrlName);

    [DllImport("wininet", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool DeleteUrlCacheGroup(long GroupId, int dwFlags, IntPtr lpReserved);

    [DllImport("wininet",  EntryPoint = "FindFirstUrlCacheEntryA",  SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindFirstUrlCacheEntry(string lpszUrlSearchPattern, IntPtr lpFirstCacheEntryInfo, ref int lpdwFirstCacheEntryInfoBufferSize);

    [DllImport("wininet",  SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindFirstUrlCacheGroup(int dwFlags, int dwFilter, IntPtr lpSearchCondition, int dwSearchCondition, ref long lpGroupId, IntPtr lpReserved);

    [DllImport("wininet", EntryPoint = "FindNextUrlCacheEntryA",  SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool FindNextUrlCacheEntry(IntPtr hFind, IntPtr lpNextCacheEntryInfo, ref int lpdwNextCacheEntryInfoBufferSize);

    [DllImport("wininet",  SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool FindNextUrlCacheGroup(IntPtr hFind, ref long lpGroupId, IntPtr lpReserved);
    #endregion

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFOA
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public uint dwStructSize;

        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public IntPtr lpszSourceUrlName;

        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public IntPtr lpszLocalFileName;

        [FieldOffset(12)]
        public uint CacheEntryType;

        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public uint dwUseCount;

        [FieldOffset(20)]
        public uint dwHitRate;

        [FieldOffset(24)]
        public uint dwSizeLow;

        [FieldOffset(28)]
        public uint dwSizeHigh;

        [FieldOffset(32)]
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME LastModifiedTime;

        [FieldOffset(40)]
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ExpireTime;

        [FieldOffset(48)]
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME LastAccessTime;

        [FieldOffset(56)]
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME LastSyncTime;

        [FieldOffset(64)]
        public IntPtr lpHeaderInfo;

        [FieldOffset(68)]
        public uint dwHeaderInfoSize;

        [FieldOffset(72)]
        public IntPtr lpszFileExtension;

        [FieldOffset(76)]
        public uint dwReserved;

        [FieldOffset(76)]
        public uint dwExemptDelta;
    }
    public static void ClearCache()
    {
        bool flag;
        bool flag1;
        long num = (long)0;
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        IntPtr zero = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr intPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool flag2 = false;
        intPtr = FindFirstUrlCacheGroup(0, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref num, IntPtr.Zero);
        if ((intPtr == IntPtr.Zero ? true : 259 != Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                flag = true;
                if ((259 == Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() ? false : 2 != Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()))
                {
                    flag2 = DeleteUrlCacheGroup(num, 2, IntPtr.Zero);
                    if ((flag2 ? false : 2 == Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()))
                    {
                        flag2 = FindNextUrlCacheGroup(intPtr, ref num, IntPtr.Zero);
                    }
                    if (flag2)
                    {
                        flag1 = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        flag1 = (259 == Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() ? false : 2 != Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    }
                    if (!flag1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            intPtr = FindFirstUrlCacheEntry(null, IntPtr.Zero, ref num1);
            if ((intPtr == IntPtr.Zero ? true : 259 != Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()))
            {
                num2 = num1;
                zero = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(num2);
                intPtr = FindFirstUrlCacheEntry(null, zero, ref num1);
                while (true)
                {
                    flag = true;
                    INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFOA structure = (INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFOA)Marshal.PtrToStructure(zero, typeof(INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFOA));
                    if (259 != Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
                    {
                        num1 = num2;
                        flag2 = DeleteUrlCacheEntry(structure.lpszSourceUrlName);
                        if (!flag2)
                        {
                            flag2 = FindNextUrlCacheEntry(intPtr, zero, ref num1);
                        }
                        if (!(flag2 ? true : 259 != Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else if ((flag2 ? false : num1 > num2))
                        {
                            num2 = num1;
                            zero = Marshal.ReAllocHGlobal(zero, (IntPtr)num2);
                            flag2 = FindNextUrlCacheEntry(intPtr, zero, ref num1);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(zero);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But, how do I delete cache for a specific site?

Comment: this will clear all cache of your IE, if you want to clear cache for a specific site call  DeleteUrlCacheEntry url, it will Delete cache of specific url