# How to clear browser cache programatically using JS or HTML

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I try to clear the chrome browser cache using Add-ons. I am developing as a site using JSP with java, I need to clear the browser cache for the security reason. I tried many ways to clear the cache but none seems to work. Any ideas?
Please let me know..

Comment: There's already an answer that might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's **no way** a browser will let you clear its cache. It would be a huge security issue if that were possible. This could be very easily abused - the minute a browser supports such a "feature" will be the minute I uninstall it from my computer.

What you can do is to tell it not to cache your page, by sending the appropriate headers or using these meta tags.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8155121/5437621

Comment: This is not true. you can via `caches.keys()` and `caches.delete(cacheKey)` as described in detail here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache

Answer (score 2):

[`Cache.delete()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/delete)

can be used for new chrome, firefox and opera.

try it please in js File

Answer (score 1):

- call `window.location.reload(true)` for a ctrl+F5 from script.
- In the new version of browsers `Cache.delete()`
- in meta tag

---

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

- in jQuery
  `$('html[manifest=saveappoffline.appcache]').attr('content', '');`

Comment: Thnks for your effort.  But it will not work for me..