# How should I build web app tool to assist in clearing cache faster during development?

Tags: javascript, python, caching, web

Thank you for reading this and thank you even more for helping.

I'm fairly new to web development and I've noticed it's a two or three step process to clear cache. Now I know there might be similar apps in existence, but I thought this would be a good exercise for growth; I just have a few questions. 
Can this be done with Javascript or should I use Python?
Is this a reasonable project for an amateur to take up? 
Are there any tips or tools of the trade a veteran might pass along to a green belt for creating such an app?

Again thank you for reading.

Comment: Which cache are you referring to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically empty browser cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache)

Comment: Where the data of a previously visited website would be stored.

Comment: I don't think it's too similar with the situation posted by blendenzo. I'm going to be using it as a tool to clear cache when making changes to code, to be able to see the change.

Comment: So you're talking about emptying the entire browser cache? Or just data associated with the current page's domain?

Comment: Yes, the entire browser cache, but potentially only recent cached items.