# How to clear Network Cache using JavaScript without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I am using setInterval to call Rest API's from my web page in about every 60 seconds. Now it is making request and hogging Network with too much request due to which after sometime my page becomes slow and non-responsive.

Can anyone help me out about how to clear Network Tab cache in Dev tools without refreshing page.
P.S. I don't want to clear all of Cache just the Network cache after 5 min.

Comment: May be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache

Comment: I don't want to clear the app cache, just Network cache only.

Comment: I think it is same , you may not able to clear the cache

Comment: Is there anything else can I do which don't hog page ?

Comment: how about  exploring websocket? the change may be big but i think that is better. Else you can change the interval in setInterval to some higher value. Another thing you can do is use of promise.  Call the rest api only when current one is done. You can check ` Promise resolve`

Answer (score 1):

You cam use `caches.delete(cacheName)`.

```
caches.keys().then(function(names) {
    for (let name of names)
        caches.delete(name);
});
```

But it is not supported in IE. For more details and browser supports, check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage/delete)

Comment: Do Network Cache has some sort of cacheName? 
Because I dont think it has.

Comment: Cache can not exist without name. Check https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/cache-api