# How to clear the cache using Jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When the gallery photo uploads, the thumbnail image gets displayed in model(using jquery and php with ajax) after updating the old image to newer one. But next time on opening the model it shows the older one, after refresh the page only it shows the newer image. Please any one give me the solution for my problem? 
Thanks in advance.

here is my code -

$.ajax({
    cache:false,
})

```
 $.ajax({
   url: 'model_appmaster.php',
   type: 'POST',
   async: true,
   data: {},    
   dataType: 'html',
   cache:false,
})
```

cache is not clearing from the below code -

```
$.ajax({
   cache:false,
})
```

Comment: apply cache:true

Comment: The doc clearly states that the `cache: false` only work with `HEAD` or `GET` request

Comment: You can better understand the details about cache management 
 here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache/8155121#8155121.

Comment: Right, then for POST method what should use?

Comment: Show us the actually problematic part - what you are doing with the image. (I have a slight suspicion that your problem might not be caching of the actual AJAX request here in the first place.)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url

Comment: `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });`

Comment: The solution is probably "Forget about Ajax entirely. Look at your `<img>`. Don't recycle the URL for the thumbnail image" but your question doesn't include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

you can try using JavaScript `window.location.replace()` function:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; http://www.redirecturl.com/" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.replace('URL');
</script>`
```

Comment: I need for ajax call cache clear. There is any solution please ping me.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').each(function(){

      var date = new Date;
      // add the current unix timestamp in microseconds to the the image src as a query string
      this.src = this.src + '?' + date.getTime();
   });

});
</script>