# How to clean the browser cache, each time a new version of the web application is deployed? Only nextjs

Tags: next.js

It has already been well explained in [this section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57993791/how-to-clean-the-browser-cache-each-time-a-new-version-of-the-web-application-i)

We cannot clear the user's browser cache due to security issues.

One solution is to set the caching time to zero.
The second solution: We communicate the values ​​of the api version through a header with the Api and based on that the uploads are done.

Other than these two solutions, how can we update the front-end side after providing a new version of the application and not allow the browser to be cached?

Comment: For most cache use cases next.js does a good job. Did You checkout this? https://nextjs.org/docs/going-to-production#caching. If users work in a hydrated app, possibly browser will not hit server while navigating. Perhaps explain your use case more detailed.