# Jquery clear browser cache chrome

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I want to clear the browser cache (chrome) with a reload button for the users to click it and reload the page. I tried

```
location.reload(true);
```

This works fine in Firefox. But not in chrome. I searched for this if its possible. A lot of people write that i need the change meta tags but this do not work for me. I want that the users cache the site and only if they hit the reloaded button it should clear the cache.

I do not use a serviceworker so this

```
Cache.delete()
```

could not help me.

If it doesnt work for chrome or other browsers this would help me too. Thanks!

Comment: I am not convinced it is possible, but I'm struggling to find definitive evidence that says either way.

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this? There may be other options.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache

Comment: @Ouroborus sometimes in the system something looks wrong and the users should easy clear the cache.  To tell the users how to clear the cache is to complicated for them

Comment: Usually CTRL+F5 or CTRL+SHIFT+R will force a cacheless reload.

Comment: @Grumpy with the meta tags i tried but did not work. The other things are for serviceworker and manifest that i do not use so this is no solution for me. The version to change the name of the css and js files work kind of but not the solution i want. The other thinks are more like for permanent no caching. But thanks for your search!

Comment: @Ouroborus yeah but the users are not that easy to handle thats why i want the button