# How to make an Anchor Tag link erase past visited page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a anchor tag. For the first time(color deep blue link) when I click it, it redirects me to my dynamic graph which forms a curve, you can see the curve being rendered.

But when for the second time when I click the anchor tag(pale pink color), it redirects me to the same dynamic graph but the graph is already loaded/rendered, you don't see the curve being rendered.

**Can I solve this problem, as I always want the link and graph react as if its always rendered for the first time**

How to solve this by either using JavaScript or PHP.
Thanks in advance.

[Image showing link has already been visited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf5BL.png)

Comment: disable [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) `Cache-Control:no-cache`

Comment: @Anilkumar is it on the anchor tag <a href="graph.php">2.5 or less</a><br>

Comment: Set cache on server side. If use fetch api, fetch api has cache options. Temporary cache clean by open console and check disable cache options.

Comment: You forgot to share the code involved

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have issue with just colour of the link then you can change the colour in css

```css
a:visited{
    color: ' #00008B'
    }
```

2. For re-rendering the links on map . Try clearing cache because browsers stores cache of the all websites that you have visited. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155064/how-to-programmatically-empty-browser-cache) talks about how programmatically empty browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

You could trick the browser by changing the URL everytime by adding a random parameter. You may name it totally different if you like.

```
printf('<a href="graph.php?rand=%s">Visit my graph</a>', microtime(true));
```

So the URL looks like different on every call and won't get the cache hit, because it is not the same.

```
<a href="graph.php?rand=1670596569.4425">Visit my graph</a>
<a href="graph.php?rand=1670596599.099">Visit my graph</a>
```

Comment: my anchor tag carry data, as i will retrieve them in the other page. will it be a problem if i do your method

Comment: As I did not see the original code of your links, I can't tell for sure. But I think it will work. Important is (for that kind of anti caching tick), that the links is always different.