# Clearing caches of browser by javascript sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser, clear-cache

How can I clear all cache of browser by javascript?
Thank

I tried some codes that I found from ai chats.
I saw some ways to solve in this problem but they didn't work please help me to solve this problem I use version or reload but they didn't work thank you. I want a javascript code that works sometimes.
If it's possible I don't want use versions .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8155064

Comment: Can you just imagine if you went to a website and it cleared  your browser cache? Not good and also not possible.